# How can I restore all Reminders data from a backup of macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, backup, reminders

I wanted to mark all reminders in a group as not complete. On my iPhone I selected the group and pressed 'clear' thinking that meant 'mark as not complete' but no, that means delete. @#$%^&* Who writes this stuff? Is there a rubbish bin from whence I can restore? No.

Because I'm syncing reminders btw Mac, iPhone and iPad on iCloud, those reminders are now gone from everywhere.

Anyway,  the Apple support web site says that I can restore reminders from iCloud — great! but, only if I'm still running an old version of Reminders, not 'Upgraded Reminders', which I am. So, if I upgrade, I lose the restore function. Again, who writes this stuff?

But wait, I take regular backups — to the point where I have hourly snapshots, at least for the last 24 hrs, so I should be able to restore from there. I have looked and searched but I can't find which files the reminders are stored in.

I don’t see an export / import feature so I wonder if restoring my Reminders from a backup of my Mac HDD is possible?

Many thanks in advance and please forgive my sarcasm — it's been a frustrating morning.

Running Monterey 12.4